# How can I carry a database created in dbDesigner to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I created a small database in dbDesigner which includes 4 tables, and I want to add these tables with their relationships to a database on a SQL Server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for this that I am aware of, is using [Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961)'s functionality for this.
The following steps will produce a file containing an SQL script you can run on any server you want in order to import the schema (with or without the data).

- **Right click** on you database.
- Select **Tasks** > **Generate scripts**
- Click **Next**
- Choose **Script entire database  and all database objects**
- Select **Save to file** and **Single file**
- If you want to export data as well, click on **Advanced** and change **Types of data to script** to **Schema and data** (default is schema only)
- Click **Next** ... **Next**.
- Run the generated file on the server you want to import the schema to.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]